# C# HMAC Implementation

Tags: c#, cryptography, hmac, password-encryption

I want my application to encrypt a user password, and at one time password will be decrypted to be sent to the server for authentication. A friend advise me to use HMAC. I wrote the following code in C#:

```
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] key = encoding.GetBytes("secret");
HMACSHA256 myhmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(key);
byte[] hashValue = myhmacsha256.ComputeHash(encoding.GetBytes("text"));
string resultSTR = Convert.ToBase64String(hashValue);
myhmacsha256.Clear();
```

How to decode the password (resultSTR, in this case)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An HMAC (Hashed Message Authentication Code) is not encryption, it's hash function (in this case SHA-256) plus some secret key. It's lossy, there is no way to derive the plaintext from the HMAC.

If you want to encrypt some secret data, you should consider using the ProtectedData class instead. More infom including sample code at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx

Comment: How do you send ProtectedData to a server?

Comment: Assuming the computers are in the same domain, you can simply send the blob returned by ProtectedData and have the same account decrypt the blob. it's all seamless :)

one of the design goals of the Data Protection API (DPAPI) in Windows, is to have a blob sit naked on the Internet and still be protected. :)